# Jsoup find the nearest href

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup, href

I have a map of strings, basically what I am doing at the moment is getting the Page body and splitting it into words by using `jsoup.getPageBody().split("[^a-zA-Z]+")` and then iterating through the page body and checking if any of the words exist in my map of strings, such as below:

```
for (String word : jsoup.getPageBody().split("[^a-zA-Z]+")) {
    if (wordIsInMap(word.toLowerCase()) {
        //At this part word is in string of maps
    }
}
```

When I am at the inside of the loop, I would like to get the closest hyperlink(href). The distance is determined by the amount of word. I couldn't find any examples like that on jsoup documentation page. How can I do that?

An example is for this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_in_American_television

If the map of strings are `race` and `crucial` then I want to get:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeders%27_Cup_Classic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Broadcasting_Company

these two links.

Comment: What are the words in your map of strings? Are they html elements? are they words in the content of the page?

Comment: They are words given by the user

Comment: if you have some example html you could show it would make it easier to visualize what we're talking about

Comment: I actually use wikipedia pages. Such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_in_American_television

Comment: So you are trying to capture the links on the tables which are closest to some word you give it? so if I gave it the word 'systems' it would return the link for 'Time Warner Cable'. as an example

Comment: @DangerDan yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a super simple implementation which should get you started. It doesn't find the link closest based on number of words though. Ill leave that up to you to modify.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

import java.util.List;

public class Program {

public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
    String searchFor = "online and";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_in_American_television").get();
    Element element = doc.getElementsContainingOwnText(searchFor).first();

    Node nodeWithText = getFirstNodeContainingText(element.childNodes(), searchFor);
    Element closestLink = getClosestLink(nodeWithText);

    System.out.println("Link closest to '" + searchFor + "': " + closestLink.attr("abs:href"));
}

private static Element getClosestLink(Node node) {
    Element linkElem = null;
    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        linkElem = element.getElementsByTag("a").first();
    }
    if (linkElem != null) {
        return linkElem;
    }

    // This node wasn't a link. try next one
    linkElem = getClosestLink(node.nextSibling());
    if (linkElem != null) {
        return linkElem;
    }

    // Wasn't next link. try previous
    linkElem = getClosestLink(node.previousSibling());
    if (linkElem != null) {
        return linkElem;
    }

    return null;
}

private static Node getFirstNodeContainingText(List<Node> nodes, String text) {
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        if (node instanceof TextNode) {
            String nodeText = ((TextNode) node).getWholeText();
            if (nodeText.contains(text)) {
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain the use of `getFirstNodeContainingText()` method?

Comment: that method takes a list of nodes and simply loops over them starting at the first one. It looks at nodes that are text nodes (not links or html nodes) and if the content of the node matches the text that node is returned and the search is finished. So that finds the actual node containing the text.